# kendoui template DELETE and EDIT

Tags: jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to make kendo template for: EDIT, DELETE.

```
{
    field: "Action",
    template: '<a href="../edit/custom" ><span> EDIT</span></a> <a href="" class="deleteCustom"><span> DELETE</span>'
}
```

When I click on delete I need a confirmation popup, after that redirect to url to delete and refresh kendo but

```
$('.deleteCustom').onclick..
```

does not work. I tried make in a field template + command

```
{ field: "Activate", width: "100px",
                            template:"<span>edit<span>"
                            command: ["destroy"], title: " ", width: "160px",

                            },
```

but template dissapears. Why? Is command overlapping? Should I position left or something?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your first template has a semantic issue. You're not closing the last `<a>` tag:

```
{
    field: "Action",
    template: '<a href="../edit/custom"><span>EDIT</span></a> <a href="" class="deleteCustom"><span>DELETE</span></a>'
}
```

Then you should use jQuery's `on()` to bind a click to your delete/edit links:

```
$('.deleteCustom').on('click', function() {
    // Here goes your confirmation...
});
```

To get row information you should use this:

```
$('.deleteCustom').on('click', function() {
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));

    if (window.confirm("Are your sure to delete " + dataItem.title + "?")) {
        location.href = "delete/" + dataItem.id;
    }
});
```

Considering that `grid` is the kendo grid instance.

Comment: to get the kendo Grid it would be `var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");`

Comment: thank yoyu very much.  i will try you're suggestion.

Comment: @studentsss did you have a feedback for this?

Comment: yes, in the end i have used jus template. and did work for me. thanks a lot